# Can't remotely access my IP Camera

Tags: port-forwarding, remote-access, ip-camera

I got a Foscam(FI9821W) IP camera, which I can access on LAN, but not from outside! It has port forwarded on my Netgear router, DDNS available, I even put it on DMZ on router, disabled my firewall, still not able to even access the login page!

Canyouseeme.org shows every port I try, as unsuccessful! Thought the problem could be my wireless router, so I tried different wireless router brands(TP-Link,D-Link...) same thing!

Any idea?!

Comment: What exact url do you use to access the camera inside your network and which ports did you forward on your router to the IP of the camera?

Comment: Internal IP: 192.168.1.50:8080 gives me full access on my camera. While external IP: 46.19.xxx.255:8080 shows nothing! Also its manufacturer's DDNS: http://http://as67xx.myfoscam.org:8080/  Ports forwarded 8080

Comment: Did you both forward UDP and TCP? or just TCP? BTW. are you sure you have a public IP ending in `.255`? I've never seen that.

Comment: Other then the UDP forwarding, if your public ip really ends in `.255` maybe that the problem. See [here](http://www.wimpyprogrammer.com/dont-host-on-a-255-ip-address/).

Comment: @Rik: Yeah both TCP/UDP. And about the IP, yes that's what whatismyip.com shows! Weird!

Comment: Well apparently providers **are** using the IP-addresses ending in `.255`. If you're one of them you might want to change it if you plan on hosting (i.e. your camera) with the internet. You could try changing your mac-adres of your router if it's directly connected to the wire (triggering a new IP). Otherwise you need to go through your provider to request a change of public ip. See [here](http://forums.comcast.com/t5/Basic-Internet-Connectivity-And/Why-am-I-assigned-255-broadcast-IP/td-p/1057633) (should also apply to other providers).

Comment: @Rik: Well then I should request a new IP, to see if that solves the prob. Thanks.